# Bash does not see the installed sass

Tags: bash, sass, path

I use windows 10.

I installed sass (1.26.3, Dart implementation) by downloading and unarchiving the archive from GitHub — https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/releases/tag/1.26.3.

The version of sass in the command prompt displays correctly — 1.26.3.

Files are compiled from .scss to .css correctly too: the command prompt displays the corresponding message: «Compiled sass\style.scss to css\style.css». The compilation works — the .scss file is compiled to CSS file.

When I use Bash and enter the command: «sass --version» — returns this result: «bash: sass: command not found» [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWm81.png).

I added a path to sass in the PATH [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlLnR.png).

I add to .bash_profile this string: «export PATH="/c/tools/dart-sass:$PATH"», — path to installed sass: disk С: in the «tools» folder.

Tell me, please, how do I set a path to sass so that I can use Bash?

Comment: What happens when you run `where sass` in Git Bash? I think I may have run into the same problem and fixed it. Maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, and it looks like a problem with how Gitbash handles (or doesn't handle) bat files rather than a path problem.

If I use the full bat file name `sass.bat --version` in Gitbash, it does work. (I haven't tried this with actual Sass compiling, though.)

It looks like the most correct solution would be to convert the .bat file to a .sh file, which GitBash handles natively. I haven't been able to find an example of this done with the sass.bat file, but it's not that complex a batch file so if you care enough you can probably make it happen.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue given the exact same installation approach and use of gitbash.  As @user15026833 mentioned using the full `sass.bat` command was successful for me as well.  Setting an alias in .bash_profile `alias sass="sass.bat"` allowed me to use `sass test.scss test.css` to compile which worked as expected.

Full disclosure, this is my first time using Sass, will update if I encounter any other issues with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
export PATH="$(cygpath -u '<<copy the directory from file manager here>>')":$PATH
```